# Loop through Parsing Function in sql

Tags: sql, loops, parsing

I have a simple parser function set up that accepts a parameter to parse a field and a parameter to define the delimiter. Here's an example of the parse functionality:

```
SELECT stringValue
FROM parseString('ABC,123', ',')
```

Output:

`stringValue
ABC
123`

I want to be able to loop through this so that the parser runs for each row in an executed query. I'm able to run a query like so:

```
DECLARE @UserID varchar(10) = 'BA123'
SELECT *
FROM dbo.parseString((SELECT GroupList FROM UserFile WHERE UserID = @UserID), ',')
```

which will return a list of all the groups that user BA123 is a member of. 
I want to be able to run a list of user IDs through this function to return a list of all users' groups. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That's not ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 3):

No need for a Loop.
However, you are wanting to run a table-valued function for every row in another table.

To do this, you must use `CROSS APPLY`.:

try this:

```
DECLARE @UserID varchar(10) = 'BA123'
SELECT * FROM UserFile u
CROSS APPLY dbo.parseString(u.GroupList, ',')
WHERE u.UserID = @UserID
```

If you want ONLY the String Values from the Function, then do this instead.

```
DECLARE @UserID varchar(10) = 'BA123'
SELECT ps.* FROM UserFile u
CROSS APPLY dbo.parseString(u.GroupList, ',') ps
WHERE u.UserID = @UserID
```

Your Database compatability needs to be 90 or greater for this to work.

Comment: What do you mean by dp?

Comment: It should probably be noted that this is a table-value function

Comment: Sorry... I meant to type "do" and not "dp".  I edited answer

Comment: Okay, can you post the SQL for the stored procedure then?

Comment: I actually found the parsing function online at http://sqlfool.com/2011/05/string-parsing-function/. I left the code as is, completely unmodified.

Comment: Did you try the code above, I briefly looked at the function, and it returns a table, but doesn't require a table as an input parameter.  It only requires a string of up to 8000 characters and the delimiter.  It then returns the resultant split as a table.

Comment: It's important to note that it will return a table for each row where the userID is a match.

Comment: I tried running the query you supplied, but I received the following error: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.parseString", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: I checked the db and this function is displayed as an available table-valued function.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use `Cross Apply`.  I copied that script to create the function on a test database of mine, and tested this functionality.